# Class not found even if it's imported

Tags: java, eclipse, class

i have a class in my program i'm developing. It's the [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) class for reading and handling csv files.

It's imported in my classpath in eclipse and also by `import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.*;`. Eclipse is not showing any errors and it fails on this `Class.forName("au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader", false, null);`

and i just can't get my head around why it fails on this line. I even tried to import all the source code into my project but it allways fails on ClassNotFound error. It's a jsp application running on apache tomcat 6 server.

Comment: Do you launch the application through eclipse as well?

Comment: i forgot to mention this one too... it's a jsp application running on tomcat

Comment: Updated my answer. Make sure the opencsv library is on the classpath for your webapplication.

Answer (score 3):

You need to fully qualify the class name. Try

```
Class.forName("au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader", false, null);
```

From the docs of [`Class.forName`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29):

> *Given the **fully qualified name for a class or interface** (in the same format returned by getName) this method attempts to locate, load, and link the class or interface.*

The `import` statement is used in compile-time only. (There is no trace of the `import` in the bytecode.) Thus the class loader that is asked to load a `"CSVReader"` can't know which package you're talking about (and actually just looks for the class in the default package).

---

Regarding your updates...

You need to make sure that the opencsv library is on the classpath for your web-application. It is not sufficient for it to be around during compilation...

Comment: sorry ... forgot to update my description... i tried this before posting and it allways fails on this.

Comment: it is in my classpath which is also exported with the application.

Comment: recheck your spelling and make sure you can use the library at runtime. If it's on your class-path and you have sufficient permissions, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Are the required classes in WEB-INF/lib or WEB-INF/classes of the deployed .war file?

Comment: i dont export it yet ... i run the apache server from eclipse who should do it when i run the server ---- i tried exporting it and it's not in there... which is strange

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the csv jar file to src folder and then do the following: 
Your Project -> right click -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Jar -> yourjar.jar

If you already have the csv jar file in src folder, try creating a new folder "lib" in the main project folder and add this csv jar file to it and follow the above steps.

Answer (score 0):

you should use FQCN(fully qualified class name) for [Class.forName()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29).